# How to substring physical files in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cmd, command-prompt

I have this .txt files from Server A, i need to do Routine A with it, if the .txt files is older than 1 day, Routine A will be executed... I have this existing code, but only counts for the number of files then perform rountine A...

Example(file from Server A): file_item.20151109.txt - since its dated November 9, i need the Routine A to be executed... any idea how I can based the execution of Routine A from the physical file?

Any idea why I cant make this work?

```
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tblFiles') > 0 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tblFiles
END
CREATE TABLE #tblFiles (FileNames varchar(1000))

SET @CmdShell = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''' + 'Dir ' + @SourceCode + ' /b'' '
INSERT INTO #tblFiles exec (@CmdShell)
Set @RowCnt = @@RowCount - 1

IF @RowCnt is not null
--=3 and (@MaxLogProcDt < @MaxOPTProcDt)
--IF (@MaxLogProcDt < @MaxOPTProcDt)
BEGIN   
        DECLARE cFileName CURSOR FOR    
        SELECT * FROM #tblFiles
        OPEN cFileName
        FETCH NEXT FROM cFileName INTO @FileName

SELECT @Test = SUBSTRING(@FileName, 11,8)
--WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)    
END

IF @Test = @YYYYMMDD
--BEGIN ROUTINE A
ELSE
--HOUSEKEEP FILES ROUTINE
```

Comment: ill be disregarding the rowcount line, i need to perform routine A based on the filename(which have dates YYYYMMDD) of the physical files or modified date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the last modified date on the file, then subtract it from now and do Routine based on the difference, modified to use the cursor in your comment.

```
if exists(select 1 from tempdb..sysobjects where name='##temp')
drop table ##temp
create table ##temp(mdate varchar(8000))
insert ##temp
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\' 
set rowcount 5
delete from ##temp
set rowcount 0
--select * from ##temp
delete top(3) FROM ##temp where mdate in (select top (3) mdate from ##temp order by mdate asc) 
--select * from ##temp

DECLARE FileCursor 
CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT mdate
  FROM ##temp 
  WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, SUBSTRING(mdate, 1, 20), GETDATE() ) < 1 

DECLARE @A VarChar(8000)
OPEN FileCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @A

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    --Do Routine A
    PRINT @A
    FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @A
END

CLOSE FileCursor
DEALLOCATE FileCursor
```

Comment: set rowcount n is for? what does this line do? select top(1) substring(mydate,1,20) as 'Last modified date' from ##tmp

Comment: set rowcount 5 limits the result set of the exec to 5 rows, the last delete basically cuts away the header from the dir. May need to experiment to get this right. i.e. you need to do a dir on your system and look at how the formating is, then cut away what you don't need and grab the date from the right line with a substring.

Comment: Modified the answer code, this runs on my system. I made a new text file and got this result                                                                                      (72 row(s) affected)

(5 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)
Nov 10 2015  1:08AM

Comment: edited my question, mind if you look at my codes, your help is much appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you are testing against (@YYYYMMDD), a specific date? If you have done  a dir on your system, you will see that there are rows in the output that contains other things than filenames and dates, you need to strip those out. That is what I do with the set rowcount 5, 0 and delete from ##temp, top 5 and bottom 3 (might only be 2 though, not sure if the null line should be counted). That way the cast to datetime for your test will always work.

Comment: Modified the answer to give you the entire row in the cursor, that way you can get the filename in the loop. The above give me each file that was changed within a day in the specified directory, when I run it on my system.

Comment: please see above, i modified my code, i was able to substring the physical files date, but I cant loop through the folder, any idea why? Whenever the Test variable is not equal to @YYYYMMDD it falls to ELSE statement and ends the procedure immediately, without checking the other files. Your thoughts? Where do I need to place the looping?

Comment: I have given you the answer already in the code above. First you create the temporary file, next a cursor that filters out today's files, last loop through the cursor and do something for each file. Some of the steps might be contracted some, like the first 2, but this way makes is easier to understand. Looks like you are missing the while loop in your code.